# Understanding how changing current relates to induced EMF for an inductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, maxwell-equations

When deriving the voltage drop across an inductor, we can consider a loop as shown that starts at terminal $a$ and goes through the coil to terminal $b$ before returning to terminal $a$ outside (in a region with no magnetic fields). Faraday's law gives:
$$
\oint \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l} = - \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int \mathbf{B} \cdot d\mathbf{S}
$$
[image]

Following [Feynman's derivation](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_22.html), we find that the potential drop $V$ is given by
$$
V = - \int_b^a \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l} = -\oint \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l}= - \mathcal{E} = L \frac{dI}{dt}
$$

This makes sense that the potential at $a$ is larger than at $b$ when $\frac{dI}{dt}>0$. However which comes first: 1) the difference in potential or 2) the increasing current?

Using Faraday's law we say this EMF/voltage is ***induced*** by the changing current, however how does one create a changing current unless there is a voltage drop to begin with?
$\frac{dI}{dt}$ suggests that the charges are accelerating. Charges accelerate down a potential difference when they move from a area of high potential to low potential.
So surely the voltage must be higher at point $a$ than point $b$ in order for $\frac{dI}{dt}$ to be increasing beforehand, rather than it being induced to be that way?

Or, are we considering the increasing current to be outside and independent of the element (i.e. using the lumped element model, we ignore any of the effects inside the inductor)?

**Edit:**
Does the derivation assume that the changing current is already there before the inductor is considered (e.g. AC voltage source)? Now when we place an inductance in the path of this changing current, an EMF is induced that then instantaneously reduces the rate of change of the current. But, the changing current is originally caused by an ***external*** potential difference, not the induced one in the inductor?

Comment: dI/dt is the tendency of change of current.

Comment: The chicken or the egg...

Answer (score 1):

> However which comes first: 1) the difference in potential or 2) the increasing current?

In usual analysis of circuits (like the example from Feynman) they are both present at the same time. There is no delay. The common expression "changing current induces EMF" is not meant to say there is a delay between the two. The effect of changing current is instantaneous. This is because we are intentionally simplifying the model; we are assuming propagation of EM field changes is infinitely fast. This is a good approximation in common situations (small circuits, low enough frequencies).

But strictly speaking, changes of current in some wire element affect other distant parts of the circuit with some non-zero delay, due to finite speed of propagation of EM field changes.

> Using Faraday's law we say this EMF/voltage is ***induced*** by the changing current, however how does one create a changing current unless there is a << voltage drop>> to begin with?

That term in <<>> brackets should be "potential drop".
Current in conductor can change as a result of action of some electromotive force. One such electromotive force can be due to differences of potential (electrostatic part of electric field), another can be due to the other part of electric field (induced electric field), such as when there is induced electric field due to other accelerating charges or moving magnet near the conductor.

For example, if we have a circular ring, we can induce induced EMF in it by quickly moving a magnet pole towards the plane of the ring. This induced EMF in the ring has nothing to do with voltage (potential difference); if the situation is completely cylindrically symmetrical, potential can be maintained the same everywhere, yet we will have induced EMF in the ring.

> Does the derivation assume that the changing current is already there before the inductor is considered (e.g. AC voltage source)? Now when we place an inductance in the path of this changing current, an EMF is induced that then instantaneously reduces the rate of change of the current. But, the changing current is originally caused by an external potential difference, not the induced one in the inductor?

If the inductor isn't connected to voltage source, there is no current anywhere to begin with. The moment it is connected to the AC source and conductive circuit is established, the inductor behaves as inductor does - it acts against change of current. This means that since current was zero before, it can't instantly jump to some big value, but it will instead continuously increase from zero to some final maximum value determined by voltage source and impedance of the inductor.

Changing current *need not* be, generally, caused by potential difference. It can be caused by any electromotive force, or sudden increase in resistance (such as disconnecting the circuit). But in your case, when inductor is connected to AC voltage source, it is; without potential difference due to the AC voltage source, current in the inductor would not change.

Comment: I have made a small edit to clarify my misunderstanding - is the external potential difference an electrostatic part of the field and it causes an induced electric field in the inductor which opposes it (but does not completely cancel it)?

Comment: @user246795 see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the voltage between a and b can be a moving magnet inside the coil. In that case there is an induced emf, even with open circuit and no current. Or it can be a charged capacitor connected in a and b, when the voltage is not induced and there is a current.

In any case, if there is a current and no ohmic resistance: $$V_{ab} = L\frac{dI}{dt}$$

Even at $t = 0$ when $I = 0$, the expression above is true. While the current is momentarily zero, its derivative is not zero.

It is like to push a car. The force and the aceleration are there together at $t = 0$, while the velocity is still zero.

Comment: What do you mean by using a charged capacitor does not induce the voltage? By Faraday's law, doesn't a changing flux always induce a voltage/EMF?

Comment: @user246795 yes, but in the case of the capacitor, the initial voltage comes from the charges. It would also be there if instead of a coil there was a resistor.